# Can't curl traefik dashboard on docker-swarm

Tags: docker, curl, docker-swarm, traefik

I'm trying to use traefik as a load balancer for one of my servers on my docker-swarm managed server.

I'm pretty much following this tutorial: https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/swarm-mode/

To break it down:

1. I init the docker swarm with

   `docker swarm init`
2. Create the overlay network

   `docker network create --driver overlay traefik-net`
3. Start the traefik-service

---

```
docker service create \
--name traefik \
--constraint=node.role==manager \
--publish 80:80 --publish 8080:8080 \
--mount type=bind,source=/var/run/docker.sock,target=/var/run/docker.sock \
--network traefik-net \
traefik \
--docker \
--docker.swarmmode \
--docker.domain=traefik \
--docker.watch \
--web
```

So, I'm trying to reach the traefik-dashboard over localhost:8080, but the page is simply not loading.

Docker is listening on these ports:

```
sudo netstat -tulpen | grep dockerd
    tcp6       2      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          56713      4102/dockerd        
    tcp6       1      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          55724      4102/dockerd
```

So I'd expect that going on localhost:8080 gives me the traefik dashboard.

Can somebody point out what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

What is the result of this two commands please :
 `curl 127.0.0.1:8080` and  `curl localhost:8080` ?

Comment: Using 127.0.0.1:8080 works just fine, while localhost:8080 does not work. is there something wrong with my docker swarm config?

Answer (score 0):

The Traefik dashboard is not exposed by default. It has to be activated via configuration first.
See: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/operations/dashboard/#secure-mode

As of now, Traefik in Docker Swarm is a little unstable when you try to manage your routing via service labels. This can be really nerve wracking when you try to debug your stuff and finally find out that the IP Traefik retrieves for a service in a Swarm is simply wrong. For more stability use a file provider for your routings.